# What does this function actually do?

Tags: binary-analysis, x64dbg

I'm taking part in this reverse engineering lab at college and we have this final big homework project. I have a part of the binary that changes it's own asm code by iterating through it's own bytes and `add`-ing or maybe `xor`-ing and then rewriting them back to memory.

I'm stuck at this function that I managed to decompile using x64dbg to the following (variable naming changed by me)

```
uint8_t fun_401c05(uint8_t argument) {
    uint8_t counter;

    counter = 0;
    if (argument) {
        do {
            counter = (uint8_t)(counter + 1);
            argument = (uint8_t)(argument & (uint8_t)(argument - 1));
        } while (argument);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly this function does. I know the function is called 3 times, each time with a letter from my input file. Each of the results is then processed using `xor` and some `sar` instruction (it's my first time seeing it) to calculate an int key that grants access to the next part of the challenge and I need to understand what the function does in order to give it the right input. I can see what it does but can't really get the meaning of it just yet..

EDIT: I know the name of the question is bad but I have no idea what other generic name to give it. If someone can help I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It counts the number of `1`'s in `argument`'s binary representation (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871204/count-number-of-1s-in-binary-representation)).

Basically, each `n & (n - 1)` cancels out the least significant `1` in `n`'s binary representation, preserving all more significant digits.

Comment: Yes, that's right.. I was able to derive my key using your tip. Thanks!